# Populating table with multiple data. Works for one line

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to populate a table using javascript and php.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $('#textbx1').html($('#textbx1').val() + $(this).attr('name') + "\r\n");
            else
            {
                var text = $('#textbx1').val();
                text = text.replace($(this).attr('name') + "\r\n" ,"");
                $('#textbx1').html(text);
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

My issue is getting this to populate a table. Currently, what I have is working to an extent. It will populate the top row in the table, but will overwrite when I try to select multiple options from the checkboxes instead of creating a new row.
I have tried using "\n" and "\r\n" as well.

My php thus far:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' rel ='textbx1' name='$item_no' \"\n\"  /> $item_no<br />";
```

populates multiple checkboxes on the page *works*

```
echo "<tr><td id=\"textbx1\" \"\n\"> </td>"; //displays using javascript above
echo "</tr>";
```

Will populate this td with only the last selection made from the checkbox. I am trying everything I know to do to get multiple $item_no to display in a table format.

Ultimately, I am trying to populate the entire table after a checkbox selection has been made. If I can figure out how to get the item_no's to work correctly, I can then move on to other variables.

For the record, I am pulling data from a MSSQL database. If you require more code, I can supply it.

Comment: It's only going to work once as you're giving each one the same ID

Comment: ahh. Thank you. Now I am off to figure out how to get different ID'd incorporated. Shouldn't be too hard.